# Suppose that the series $ \sum a_n$ converges. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that the series $\sum a_n$ converges. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}
a_n = 0$.

Not sure how to do this my attempt:

WTS:$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $|a_n - 0| < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose N such that $|a_n - 0| < \epsilon$

Suppose $n > N$, then $|a_n - 0| < \epsilon$

I am not sure.

Comment: I changed it, thank you.

Comment: The sequence of partial sums $S_n$ converges, hence the sequence $\{S_n\}$ is Cauchy. This implies for any $\epsilon > 0$ and sufficiently large $n$, we have $|S_{n+1} - S_n| < \epsilon$

Since $S_{n+1} - S_n = a_{n+1}$, the result follows

Comment: This is an excellent solution, however, from seeing the OPs work; I wonder if he knows how to show a convergent sequence is Cauchy.....

Comment: > I had to google what cauchy was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A_n := \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. Note that $a_n = A_n - A_{n-1}$.

Then, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k := \lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = L$.

Now, since the sum converges:

$$\forall \varepsilon_1 > 0: \exists N_1 \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N_1:|A_n-L| < \varepsilon_1$$

Now, we need to prove that $a_n$ goes to zero:

$$\forall \varepsilon_2 > 0: \exists N_2 \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N_2:|a_n| < \varepsilon_2$$

To prove that, let $\varepsilon_1 = \dfrac12\varepsilon_2$. Now, we have $N_1$ from the assumption. Let $N_2 = N_1+1$. For any $n > N_2$:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
|A_{n+1} - L|  &<& \dfrac12 \varepsilon_2 & \text{assumption} \\
|A_n - L|  &<& \dfrac12 \varepsilon_2 & \text{assumption} \\
|A_{n+1} - A_n|  &<& |A_{n+1} - L| + |A_n - L| & \text{triangle inequality} \\
&<& \dfrac12 \varepsilon_2 + \dfrac12 \varepsilon_2 \\
&=& \varepsilon_2 \\
|a_n| &<& \varepsilon_2 & \text{conclusion}
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}=M$ then we have that $M=\lim_{n \to \infty}({a_n} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{a_k})=\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}+\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{a_n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n+M$. Hence, we have that $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: good answer.a new proof!

Comment: Glad you like it!

Comment: This assumes that lim a_n exists

Answer (score 0):

Let $$L=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_{n}=\lim _{n\to \infty}\sum^{n}_{k=1}a_{k}=L$$
Then, $A_{n}$ is from Cauchy, that is:
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}/ n,p\geq n_{0}\rightarrow |A_{p}-A_{n}|<\epsilon$$
In particular, for $$p=n+1\rightarrow |A_{n+1}-A_{n}|<\epsilon \rightarrow \left | \sum^{n+1}_{k=1}a_{k}-\sum^{n}_{k=1}a_{k}\right|<\epsilon \rightarrow |a_{n+1}|<\epsilon\rightarrow$$
Taking $$n_{1}=n_{0}+1\rightarrow \forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}/ n\geq n_{1}\rightarrow |a_{n}-0|<\epsilon \rightarrow \lim _{n\to \infty}a_{n}=0$$